# Set cronjob/scheduled task in windows server 2003? Php & Mysql

Tags: php, windows-server-2003, scheduled-tasks, cron

I would like to set a scheduled task/cron job to update database. I planning updating the database using a php script, i.e connect to database and execute SELECT and UPDATE query. I already prepared the php script, and what should I do next?

I am (my server) is using Windows Server 2003, IIS, php and mysql.

When I google this, I got tons of results, and its confusing me. Is there any quick explanation of what should I do (step-by-step)?

(Please let me know what are the others information you need to know)

Answer (score 0):

In windows schedule task, define a task to download a file(**http://127.0.0.1/autotask.php**) every day (or minute)

then put your code in **autotask.php**